# (Generalized Cantor Set) Constructing a closed set with measure $1-\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Hello dear Mathematicians!
For every $\epsilon>0$ I want to construct a closed set $F_\epsilon$ on $[0,1]$ such that $F_\epsilon$ does not contain any closed interval $[c,d]$ and $mF_\epsilon\geq1-\epsilon$.

The cantor set is obtained by successively removing the "open middle third" from each closed interval in $K_n$ to obtain $K_{n+1}$, where $K_0=[0,1]$. Now I want to construct a generalized cantor set described above. Moreover, there is a theorem saying that If there is a closed set which is not open, then there is a nonempty closed set which does not contain any nonempty open set. But, I did not find any theorem about not containing any closed set.

I'll appreciate any hints that take me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make these sets arbitrarily close to measure $1$ in the following sense.

Define a geometric series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb N}ar^{n}<1$. As with the cantor set, remove an interval of length exactly $ar^n$ from each component in the $(n-1)^{th}$ step. Define

$$C:= \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N}C_n$$

which is closed, while $m(C_n)=1-\sum_{k=1}^{n}ar^n>0$. All we need to do is make sure that $a \cdot \frac{r}{1-r}$ is sufficiently small.

---

For reference, the cantor set is pretty much given by $\sum_{n \in \mathbb N} \frac{1}{2}(2/3)^n=1$, and $m(1-1)=0$, so it has measure zero.

---

By the way, these are known as [fat cantor sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set)

Comment: @David yeah, I'm pretty sure that would work. See my edit as well, there are more details, and different constructions etc.